# Safari doesn't seem to like certain styles on their select tags

Tags: css, select, safari, custom-controls

Safari does not allow padding even if applied as !important. You can see this [here](http://www.particletree.com/examples/safari3/drop.html).

I was wondering if anyone has found a work around for this?

**Note**: I am not looking for plug-ins, as the site is much too complex for them so that they do not meet my needs.

Warmth.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Webkit browsers (Safari and Chrome) use the OS's native controls rather than rendering menus themselves, so CSS doesn't apply to them. If you want more control in a cross-browser fashion, use a plugin like [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)

Comment: Plugins do not meet my needs. I already have custom inputs for my website, but because Safari refuses padding (Chrome does not, Chrome allows complete customization) the options are overflowing.